# Formatting pom xml with embedded groovy source

Tags: maven, groovy, indentation, pom.xml

My pom file has embedded groovy source.  When I format the xml using Eclipse Source>Format, it introduces linebreaks into the groovy source which breaks it.  How can I best resolve this?

**Update:**
The groovy is in

```
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <execution>
                <configuration>
                    <source>
```

and it appears to write a mangled version of the project.version to the manifest file.  I didn't write it.

Comment: Why have you embedded Groovy source in your pom? Can you give an excerpt of that?

Comment: Updated with as much information as I can share.

Comment: For which plugin is this configuration and execution block given? Doesn't the plugin support storage of the script as an external file? The version into the manifest is the usual behaviour of Maven if you don't change the default behaviour.

Comment: Thanks, @khmarbaise.  I will check with the author of the script and see if it can be done as you suggest.  It's the "gmaven-plugin", group "org.codehaus.groovy.maven".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have taken a look into the docs of the [gmaven-plugin](http://docs.codehaus.org/display/GMAVEN/Executing+Groovy+Code) which gives you examples like this (stolen from their web-site):

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.codehaus.gmaven</groupId>
    <artifactId>gmaven-plugin</artifactId>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <phase>generate-resources</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>execute</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
                <source>${basedir}/src/main/script/myscript.groovy</source>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```